# Use ASP.NET MVC DisplayTemplate implicitly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, display-templates

I have some code like this in a cshtml view

```
@{  int i = 0;
    foreach (var record in Model.Records)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@record.CreatedDate</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Records[i].CreatedDate)</td>
    </tr>
        i++;
    }
}
```

and in my ~/Views/Display folder I have a file called DateTime.cshtml with this in

```
<p>@ViewData.Model.ToShortDateString()</p>
```

so my view is rendering two version of the CreatedDate, one with the full DateTime string and one with the short date string.

Can I configure my ASP.NET MVC4 project to use the display template I have created whenever it displays a DateTime, without calling DisplayFor explicitly? ie how can the line '@record.CreatedDate' use my DateTime template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. there is no way to configure MVC to use a template with this code:

```
'@record.CreatedDate'
```

You will have to keep using `DisplayFor` which isn't too much to write by the way...